# Loading php extension for specific domain only

Tags: php, apache, lamp

I have a dedicated LAMP server with more than one domains hosted. I want to load a php extension only for a single domain. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. What have you tried that isn't working? Also, why?

Comment: i think you neeed to make some changes on apache configuration files

Comment: why down vote? while someone is giving a good answer. I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your VirtualHost configuration.

Make a copy of php.ini file. Add the extension you need in there. Store it in separate directory.

Use PHPIniDir in your config for the particular site and point to that new dir, containing new php.ini

Restart apache.

Your config will be loaded and will use separate php.ini file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I am a bit confused. In an answer at server fault I see that "Individual virtualhosts cannot have their own PHPINIDir because......". Here is the link http://serverfault.com/questions/461702/custom-phpinidir-setting-in-virtualhost-affecting-other-virtualhosts

Am I missing something?

Comment: It is probably a problem of that parituclar server configuration. If you open a script with phpinfo() in it you will see the line with "Loaded PHP Configuration file" line, and it will point to the php.ini file it is loading for this particular site. You should edit vhost config and see phpinfo. If it loaded your custom php.ini - all is fine.

Comment: There are some hosting providers that allow you to choose PHP version for the website - like PHP 4 or PHP 5. That feature is often realized by using particular php.ini files and installing several versions of php for those files.